How can I compute bcrypt hash with less than 16 (2^4) rounds on Linux?
How can I compute bcrypt hash with less than 16 rounds (cost factor of 4 = 2^4 = 16 rounds) on Linux?
This is the same question as Compute bcrypt hash from command line, but requiring a cost factor of 1 to 3. All of the answers there only allow a cost factor of 4 or higher.
This is what they say:
> htpasswd -bnBC 3 "" Y
htpasswd: Unable to encode with bcrypt: Invalid argument

For https://bcrypt-generator.com/, setting cost to 3 or less computes a hash using a cost factor of 4 ($2a$04$Gtm/m3uLxfxcezWRLcVLBuUTNbrSse/.XsBK16WBN5u37Cl88kaFy)
For https://www.browserling.com/tools/bcrypt, Rounds exceded maximum (30)!.


How can I compute bcrypt hash with less than 16 rounds (cost factor of 4 …

This is impossible; bcrypt is defined to do at least 16 rounds. Anything below a cost factor of four is no longer bcrypt.
Running around a bit in various BSD source trees and libxcrypt: no bcrypt implementation I could find doesn't check the bounds, so you won't be able to use your weak b-alike crypt with anything. You're just inventing your own hash, and as you probably know, inventing your own crypto is usually a bad idea. I assume this is for didactic purposes to show how quickly one can crack low-iteration count hashes that were designed to be costly (and otherwise weak)? Because no other tool will accept so a non-bcrypt-but-bcrypt-alike hash, I don't think there's a ready-to-use tool like you ask for, and no other software that would work with these "broken" hashes. 
I'll have to assume you're currently writing your own tools and thus can program.
So, having looked at a few implementatons:
The OpenBSD version is the one I found most straightforward to modify.
http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/~checkout~/src/lib/libc/crypt/bcrypt.c?rev=1.58&content-type=text/plain
Set BCRYPT_MINLOGROUNDS to 0, pass a logarithmic round of 0 or 1 to bcrypt_newhash, remove the rounds bounds check in bcrypt_initsalt, and use these bcrypt functions in your program. The C seems pretty portable, and C can pretty much be called from any programming language of your choice.

Four is bcrypt's minimum cost (work factor), built into the algorithm itself by the original authors (Provos and Mazières) in 1999.
The original/reference implementation is OpenBSD's, which forces the cost to 4 if a cost less than 4 is requested.
The original selection of 4 was likely because a goal of Provos' local testing during development was for hashing to be sufficiently slow, but not "too" slow (this is a reply to my question, from Provos himself).
So while you could compile a local version of the code yourself and override this minimum, I do not recommend it (for anything other that for curiosity / testing purposes). In fact, even bcrypt cost 4 is much too slow on modern CPUs (compared to 25 years ago!). I would consider cost 10 to be the minimum today for secure production use, and cost 12 if you can get away with it.
